# Rails3: form_tag remote option doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, rjs

I want to do the following :

capture an e-mail address in a field through a form_tag helper
fire the corresponding controller to:

1. store it in a table
2. send an e-mail to that address
3. show a confirmation message

I use a partial for the form_tag:

**_confirmation.html.erb**

```
  <%= form_tag(confirmation_path, remote: true) do %>
    Please enter your e_mail address : <%= text_field_tag 'email' %><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"</button>
  <% end %>
```

confirmation_path points to route captmails#confirmation via POST.

When I run the page with the partial and I submit the e-mail address, it is wrongly looking for the template captmails/confirmation, ie the HTML template, which doesn't exist, since what I want to do a **remote** call to the corresponding captmails/confirmation.js.erb template, ie Javascript template, which is well there.

So it is like it doesn't take the 'remote: true' parameter into account.
Is there another way to do the same?

Comment: Are you saying that when you submit the form it redirects you to `confirmation_path` instead of making an Ajax request?

Comment: Could you share your controller code so we can see how you've defined respond_to/respond_with for handling JS?

Comment: Independant of what stands in the controller, it wants to load a HTML template instead of a js.erb template...

Comment: even when I write explicitly in my controller :

      render js: " << my javascript >>"

it says : "Processing by CaptmelsController#confirmation as HTML" and then it shows me my javascript as a page...

I don't get it...

Comment: Could it be because I use this form_tag from a partial, in a form that already has another remote form_tag (which works and delivers a correct "Processing by <<Controller#action>> as **JS**" ?

Comment: @Carlos Drew

my controller action response is defined as :
         respond_to do |format|
            format.js { render "confirmation" }
         end

Comment: Wait, wait, did you say you have a form nested inside another form? That's not valid HTML, and will not work. The highest level form will get submitted. Could you paste in your full view template/html output, possibly at http://gist.github.com?

Comment: I have a main form that has a 1st form_tag (which works), and when the corresponding button is activated in this 1st form, I invoke a partial with a single-field form_tag in which I want to capture an e-mail address, and then, I send an e-mail to that address, and I want to raise an alert, in javascript, in order to confirm to the user that an e-mail has been sent.
What other possibility do I have to do the same?
I don't want to show the field to enter the e-mail before the first form has been submitted, and I still want to stay on the same HTML page while doing all this. Hence my choice.

Comment: I must add that the capture of the e-mail address in that 2d form_tag in the partial works, because I send an e-mail alright.
It's just that it doesn't end up executing the javascript to raise the alert afterwards...

Comment: Could you paste the full rendered HTML after the first `remote:true` form is submitted? I understand the workflow you want, and I agree that it's good and right, but I'm not sure if the resultant HTML/page state is valid.

Comment: Main form:

<div class="form-horizontal">
  <%= form_tag({controller: "products", action: "compute"}, :method => "get", :remote => true) do %>
  
...
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-large"><i class='icon-euro icon-2x'></i></button>
  </br>
  </br>
  <div id="result">
  </div>
...
<% end %>
</div>

This 1st remote call invokes compute.js.erb (that works...):

      $('#result').empty().append('<%= j render 'result', result: $price %>')

Comment: Then the partial _result that is invoked:

        <result>The price is : <%= number_to_currency($price)+" "+@product.unit %></result>
  
      <div class="confirmation">
      <%= form_tag(confirmation_path, :method => "get", :remote => true) do %>

         Please enter your e-mail address to get a confirmation e-mail of the price : <%= text_field_tag 'email' %><%= hidden_field_tag(:product, params[:id]) %><%= hidden_field_tag(:customer_id, params[:customer_id]) %><button class="btn btn-primary" title="Send you address"><i class='icon-check'></i></button>
        <% end %>
      </div>